# pySerial reading and writing with arduino

Tags: python, tkinter, arduino, pyserial

I've got a question. I'm working on an Arduino project, and at this moment, I have a reader that writes all the data from my sensors in Tkinter. However, I also need to control digitalWrite with buttons. For example, while reading data from sensors every 1 second, when I click the button, I want to set a chosen pin to HIGH. The only method that I know is serial.write(bytes...), but I think it collides with reading data from sensors. Do you have any ideas on how to get over this issue?

this is a bit of my code:

```
def read_data():
    dataPacket = arduinoData.readline().decode('utf-8')
    dataSplit = dataPacket.split(',')
    ....
    window.after(2000, read_data)

def pumpOn():
    arduinoData.write(bytes('N', 'UTF-8'))
    
def pumpOff():
    arduinoData.write(bytes('F', 'UTF-8'))

btn_pumpOn = tk.Button(window, text ="Włącz pompę", command = pumpOn())
btn_pumpOn.pack()

btn_pumpOff = tk.Button(window, text ="Wyłącz pompę", command = pumpOff())
btn_pumpOff.pack()

read_data() // method that reads data from sensors

window.mainloop()
```

I tried to control it with interrupts but I'm stuck.

Comment: The way the code in your snipet is formatted results in  `pumpOn()`, `pumpOff()` and `read_data()` all being executed without waiting for any button clicks.

Comment: only `read_data()` is executed in loop, pump methods are activated by button

Comment: It really depends on how the application in arduino handles incoming data.

Comment: It is helpful if you can include some debug information in your question. E.g. any error messages you are getting. Looking at your snippet of code could it be the way you are setting up the `Button`? The `command` argument doesn't need the brackets on the name of the function. e.g. should it be: `btn_pumpOn = tk.Button(window, text ="Włącz pompę", command = pumpOn)
`

Comment: In other words i want my program to read data from sensors every second, but i also need to for example: write data when i click the button to change pin from LOW to HIGH and program will keep reading data after that.

Comment: Understood. But you haven't given a [minimal, reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example) so no one else can run your code. Have you tried changing the `btn_pumpOn` definition as I suggested?

Comment: It is better to set *timeout* values for read and write when creating the instance of `pyserial.Serial()`, otherwise both `.readline()` and `.write()` are blocking operations.  Also as said in other comment, `command=pumpOn()` should be `command=pumpOn` instead. Same for `command=pumpOff()`.